# Google Services - Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.99

Tags: android, google-api, dependencies, google-play-services, build.gradle

Could someone please help me understand.

This is my first time with Google Services

So following [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) website I tried compiling it. With the version 7.8.99 and it gives me the error 
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.99

I have downloaded the latest 
`Google Play Services` (revision 26)

And yet it gives me the error or is my version `7.8.99` wrong. I got the version number from 
[image: App Info Google Play Services]

I am a beginner in android development so pls do help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont known the exact vesrion use this

```
compile

'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
```

Comment: This website is the SAME I mentioned in the question. I need to know the latest version of the PLAY SERVICES.

Comment: To your first answer before editing Infact I have downloaded every thing in the SDK manager that starts with Google except the Google api's for the different platforms

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE if you dont known the exact vesrion use this   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'

Comment: I'll try it right now and let you know please wait.

Comment: Oh thank you do much. I must say the first 2 answers were bad but your 3rd one rocked the charts. But I just want to know how I can find the right version. If you know tell me  cause it gives me a warning. I know it is just warning but I am just saying AND very important please do update or edit your answer